# I want to center my UL but it doesnt works

Tags: html, css

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Why is "text-align" not working? I also tried "justify-content" but that also not works.

Comment: The reason your justify-content didn't work is due to you not setting display to flex ..Unless you did that in previous code

Comment: give it left:50%

Answer (score 2):

CSS Style-->

```
     ul {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

try inspecting the element in chrome developer tools. You will know what the problem is.
I found out that you have not used width.

to make it beautiful by removing the bullets

```
 list-style-type : none;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that you used fixed attribute in your ul. If you are going to make it aligned center, you need to define the width, otherwise it cannot be done.
You can do it like

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    // to take the whole width of screen from left to right
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    // you might start from left: 32px; and right: 32px; there if you need to make a little padding, otherwise it is better if the padding is created in the li within ul
}
```

If you define its fixed with **left: 0** and **right: 0**, it will take the whole width, or you may use

```
ul {
    ... // like before
    width: 100%
}
```

but by using **width: 100%**, there may be a risk that the element might flow out of the page. If you would use **width: 100%**, you might as well add the **left: 0;**

Hope it helps